# customizing .input-group-append in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

Can someone please inform me on how I can Customize the `border-radius` for the class `.input-group-append` ?

I'm trying to straight out the curves on this `input-group`.

I cant' find anything useful in the documentation.

I have googled around and tried various solutions but with no luck.

Below is my html and .css

this is my html

```
<div class="row" id="searchfilter">

<!--- Calendar Selection -->

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 input-group input-group-sm input-daterange">
      <select id="selector" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" title="searchFilter">
               <option>option1</option>
               <option>option2</option>
               <option>option3</option>
               <option>option4</option>
               <option>option5</option>
           </select>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">from </span>
      </div>
        <input id="startDate1" name="startDate1" data-label="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">to </span>
        </div>
        <input id="endDate1"name="endDate1" data-label="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>  <!-- Row searchFilter -->
```

and the relevant part of the .SCSS is here.

```
#searchFilter{
  margin-top: 20px;
   select, input{
     border-radius: 0px !important;
   }
.input-group-append, .input-group-prepend{
     border-radius: 0px !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach... it didn't give any result. `.input-group.input-group-sm{
  .input-group-append, .input-group-prepend{
    border-radius: 0px !important;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you inspect the element with the radius, you can see the following style:

```css
.input-group-sm>.custom-select,
.input-group-sm>.form-control,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-append>.btn,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-append>.input-group-text,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-prepend>.btn,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

So to override, you can do

```css
.input-group-sm>.custom-select,
.input-group-sm>.form-control,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-append>.btn,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-append>.input-group-text,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-prepend>.btn,
.input-group-sm>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Example bootply with the updated styles](https://www.bootply.com/AKAqmayZZU)

I would suggest wrapping the elements though and adding a class so you are not overriding all border radiuses (unless you want to)

Comment: Yes of course, thank you, I guess I'll use that approach... But is this the "valid" Bootstrap .Scss way to customize elements? - asking for curiosity

Comment: Not too sure - I don't use bootstrap as I find it has too much junk in, but if you are not wanting standard bootstrap then you should override the styles in a separate override stylesheet (included after the original and rather than changing the original) so you can easily upgrade in future if you have to